# Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans; bundle-version="1.2.200"

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to create a RCP application in which, I want to bind a variable from a bean to view.
Code for bean #

```
public class SaveFileBean implements PropertyChangeListener {
private String text;
private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(
        this);

@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("text", null, text);
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
        PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

}
```

The code for VIew

```
public class NewView extends ViewPart {
private DataBindingContext m_bindingContext;
public static final String ID = "com.app.Editor.newView";
SaveFileBean bean = new SaveFileBean();
private StyledText text;

public NewView() {
}

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    text = new StyledText(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    bindValues();

}

private void bindValues() {
}

@Override
public void setFocus() {
    // create new Context
    DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();

    // define the IObservables
    IObservableValue target = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).
      observe(text);
    IObservableValue model= BeanProperties.
      value(SaveFileBean.class,"text").observe(text);

    // connect them
    ctx.bindValue(target, model);
}
}
```

I added the following dependencies in manifest.mf Here is my MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Editor
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.app.Editor;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.app.editor.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: APP
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
   com.ibm.icu,
   org.eclipse.core.runtime,
   org.eclipse.core.databinding;bundle-version="1.4.2",
   org.eclipse.jface.databinding;bundle-version="1.6.200",
   org.eclipse.core.databinding.property,
   org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans;bundle-version="1.2.200"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy. Here is 
Export-Package: com.app.editor,
      com.app.editor.actions,
      com.app.editor.beans,
      com.app.editor.commands,
       com.app.editor.functionalities,
       com.app.editor.perspectives,
        com.app.editor.views
```

While running the code, I am getting error -

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.app.Editor    [81]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans; bundle-version="1.2.200"
```

But, I have added this dependency in MANIFEST and I can see this jar in the project.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Edit : the full log file is :

```
!SESSION 2015-08-19 08:53:21.748 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application com.app.Editor.application
Command-line arguments:  -application com.app.Editor.application -data C:\Srijani\Personal Workspace\RCP/../runtime-com.app.Editor.application -dev file:C:/Srijani/Personal Workspace/RCP/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/com.app.Editor.application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

!ENTRY com.app.Editor 4 0 2015-08-19 08:53:22.559
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.app.Editor [87]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.app.Editor 2 0 2015-08-19 08:53:22.888
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.app.Editor [87]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-19 08:53:22.888
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.app.Editor.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Are there any more messages in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory about resolution problems?

Comment: Yes, there is.... I am attaching the log file. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Eclipse RCP edition there is a view called `Target Platform State`. Is the mentioned plugin listed in there? You can filter for the name. If so, check the `Run Configuation` if the plugin is getting loaded.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Though I am not sure why this was happening.

Run As -> Run Configurations... -> Plugin-ins tab -> Add Required Plug-ins -> Validate plugin -> Run

This solved my problem!

Comment: Had a similar issue with an unresolved requirement for junit after adding some tests, so +1 - and I think you mean `Run Configurations...` > `Plug-ins` tab > `Add Required Plug-ins` button (at least in Mars).

Comment: This will **not** solve your problem when deploying your _product_ however. Still you'll have to find the missing dependencies and manually add them to your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

For me, removing the plugins and adding them again worked...
`Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform`, try remove the Running Platform target definition -> `Click Apply`, and then Restore defaults or add the required plugins which you want to add.